# Pragmatic ways to monitor Resque queues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitoring, resque

I am looking to automate the starting/restarting of queues with Resque in my Ruby on Rails application. (running on JRuby)

I want to ensure the following criteria are met:

1. Workers are started after I deploy with capistrano
2. Workers are restarted if they die for whatever reason
3. Workers eating too much memory are stopped/restarted and can fire me an email alert

Are there tools that current provide this functionality or at least a subset of it? If there isn't anything that restarts the queue/worker, I would like to be notified at minimum so I can manually do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be using a program such as [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/) or [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to get #2 and #3. For #1, you can just setup your Capistrano script to send a `kill -INT` to all the Resque workers, then the monitoring program will start them up again.

The advantaged to using `kill -INT` rather than manually stopping and starting the jobs in the Capistrano script is that your deploy won't have to wait for every worker to stop processing its job to start them back up. It also means if you have a long running job, you will quickly have whatever free workers were running on the new code as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not especially familiar with it, however I believe the [god](https://github.com/mojombo/god) gem is used frequently for process management.